# Algorithms: create segments from points on a map

Tags: algorithm, geospatial

I was wondering wether there's an existing algorithm or a way to do this:
I have many points in 2D (let's say x,y) which represent roads positions. Each road can take different directions and "split". I'd need to generate only the segments up to the split. Better explained with images:

[image: Points 2D]

These are my points

[image: Segments]

And these are the 3 segments generated

I thought using interpolation spline but that wouldn't work for this and [Ant Colony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization_algorithms)  wouldn't probably help much here as they might take shortcuts. 
Is there a way to do this and if yes, how would you do it?

Comment: It sounds like a classification problem! Have you tried SVM [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) also [link](http://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/asprs/pers/2004/00000070/00000012/art00002)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of to approach this, both involving finding the closets pairs one by one.

The first method would involve sorting the list of points along either axis, and then starting with the first point, search forward through points, measuring the distance between then. Take Pn as the nth point, we could say that the closest point to P1 is at most the distance from P1 to P2. So then we search the sorted array at most that far, and if we come across another point that is closer, say P4, we cut the distance we search even farther. Once you find the closest point, draw a segment between the two, and move on to point P2. You could probably optimize this some storing some information about the relative placement of P1 and P2, and then automatically skipping some of the elements you compared P1 to because you will already know they aren't the optimal solution for P2.

The other approach I can think of would be to use a quadtree. Divide the entire grid into 4 squares, and if any of those squares contain more than 1 element, divide them into 4 squares as well, and repeat until each square contains 0 or 1 element. Then look at the squares that contain these single squares (containing only 1 element), and compare for the nearest neighbor. Now, this does mean that you will have to manually check the squares directly adjacent to the one being searched, because it may lie on a boundary (think of one just above 1/2 way up the grid, and one just below 1/2) and you wouldn't find the other point until you 'expand' back to the original square that was the initial grid. This solution would be a bit more difficult to program I think, but could certainly prove to be faster in dense maps.